# Laravel 5.2 some routes doesn't work

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have this route:

```
Route::get('/sites', 'SitesController@index');
```

and when i run http://localhost:8880/sites it responds: 
The Browser response (404 error): The requested resource /sites was not found on this server.

The Terminal Response : Invalid request (Unexpected EOF) 
When i change the route to:

```
Route::get('/premium-sites', 'SitesController@index');
```

And run it in my browser
    http://localhost:8880/premium-sites.
Everything works like a charm.

I don't use anywhere else this route (/sites) and
all other 20 routes i have, work fine except for this.

 
I can't understand what kind of bug is this and i can't find a way to fix it.
**Update**

This is my route list

```
+--------+----------+-------------------+-----------------+-------------------------------------------------+------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI               | Name            | Action                                          | Middleware |
+--------+----------+-------------------+-----------------+-------------------------------------------------+------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | categories/{type} | categories.show | App\Http\Controllers\CategoriesController@index | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD | sites             | sites.show      | App\Http\Controllers\SitesController@index      | web        |
+--------+----------+-------------------+-----------------+-------------------------------------------------+------------+
```

I also changed the route to this:

```
Route::get('/sites', [
    'as'   => 'sites.show',
    'uses' => 'SitesController@index'
]);
```

and my controller to:

```
public function index()
{
    return 'test route';
}
```

The response is :
[image]

And the terminal response:

```
[Tue Aug 30 01:56:15 2016] ::1:61591 [404]: /sites - No such file or directory
[Tue Aug 30 01:56:15 2016] ::1:61593 [200]: /favicon.ico
[Tue Aug 30 01:56:38 2016] ::1:61594 Invalid request (Unexpected EOF)
```

Comment: can you send an output of `php artisan route:list` to show all of your routes?

Comment: unfortunately not, this will publish all my projects links. Could you please try to use the same name for a route and tell me it works for you? If i rename it to sites2 or siteswhatever it works fine. Its like "sites" is a reserved word

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am probably late for this answer. Anyways could be useful for someone.

Had this issue the other day, the reason for me was due to the existence of a the folder name "X" in the public directory which resembles the route name "X".

Most probably you are having a folder called "sites" in public directory, Either rename that or the one in the routes file

Answer (score 1):

It appears that there may be some conflict somewhere in one of your routes file.  Here is the setup I have and it is working just fine.

routes.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::get('/sites', 'SitesController@index');
});
```

route:list

```
php artisan route:list
+--------+----------+-------+------+--------------------------------------------+------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI   | Name | Action                                     | Middleware |
+--------+----------+-------+------+--------------------------------------------+------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | sites |      | App\Http\Controllers\SitesController@index | web        |
+--------+----------+-------+------+--------------------------------------------+------------+
```

Here is my controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;


class SitesController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        return 'Test Route';
    }
}
```

To debug this, I would start with `xdebug` to see if you can break at the route to see what is going on and follow the trace.  if you do not have `xdebug` set up, comment out all routes except for the `/sites` route and see if it works then.  If it does, one of your other routes is in the way.  Begin by uncommenting routes one by one or group by group and when the error re-surfaces, you are closer.

Comment: i have updated my code as you suggested but nothing, i have pasted all the screenshots and code

Comment: @H.Kontodios how are you hosting the localhost environment. Are you using `php artisan serve`?  if not, try that and then visit `localhost:8000/sites`  Maybe you are not seeing the site you are expecting to see.  Also, what is your .htaccess in public?  is there something there that is blocking /sites?

Comment: in the specific folder i run `php -S localhost:8880 -t public`
i have also tried `php artisan serve`

Comment: I think i will forget about it for the moment and give an other name to the route. I would like to thank all of you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `Route::get('/sites', 'SitesController@index');` is involved

better use this route:

```
// Sites
Route::resource('/sites', 'SitesController');
```

---

for example the route :

```
// Home
Route::resource('/home', 'HomeController');
```

have :

```
 GET|HEAD  | home                | home.index     | App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@index  
POST       | home                | home.store     | App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@store   
GET|HEAD   | home/create         | home.create    | App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@create  
DELETE     | home/{home}         | home.destroy   | App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@destroy
PUT|PATCH  | home/{home}         | home.update    | App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@update  
GET|HEAD   | home/{home}         | home.show      | App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@show    
GET|HEAD   | home/{home}/edit    | home.edit      | App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@edit
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: I tried it and it doesn't work. By the way i don't want to use a resource controller because i want only one function.

Comment: give me teamviewer if you want